# Detecting the last part of a URL not working - PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Im using this code to discover the last part of url:

```
$link = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
$link_array = explode('/',$link);
$page = end($link_array);
```

Somehow it's **not working** since i moved my project from **000webhost** to **Hostinger**.

For example  `www.google.com/hello.php/4441` should return `4441` but instead it returns `hello.php`

Someone experienced it before?

Comment: Use `var_dump()` to check that `$link_array` has content

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [documentation](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) of the `$_SERVER` variable for `PHP_SELF`

> The filename of the currently executing script, relative to the
>   document root. For instance, $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] in a script at the
>   address http://example.com/foo/bar.php would be /foo/bar.php. The
>   **FILE** constant contains the full path and filename of the current (i.e. included) file.

So this gives you the filename of the executing script, which is `hello.php`

You probably want to use the `REQUEST_URI`, which will return the whole URI, not the filename of the running script.